# Precompiled Headers with Qt and g++ (QtCreator)

Tags: qt, g++, precompiled-headers

I'm using precompiled headers on a Qt project to speed up compilation time. I'm using Qt 4.6.2 .When I compile the project using macx-g++ (meaning the g++ compiler) it doesn't include the stdafx.h automatically for each header. When compiling under xcode it will work. I'm using the PRECOMPILED_HEADER qmake constant to point at my stdafx.h.

So is it a limitation from g++? Or there a solution/work around?

Thanks for your help, 
Boris -

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes gcc ignores precompiled header if some conditions aren't met. see: [gcc documentation page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html).

Compile headers just like any other files but put the output inside a file with a suffix of .gch:

> g++ -c stdafx.h -o stdafx.h.gch
>   g++ main.cpp
>   ./main.out